# Unable to track balance for recent transaction from Phantom wallet through a website

Tags: transaction

I went to Orbitt.pro website menu tab, selected "buy on Raydium" using Solana through Raydium, received Solscan confirmation but no balance is reflecting in my Phantom wallet and I don't see any option on Raydium for tracking. What am I missing? I have attempted to add ORBT ca to Phantom wallet but don't see the option in Phantom. Confused here.